# Laravel Form Request merge new variable does not validated

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to get the new validated request after merging the request with new variable. It can be found in $request->all() but not in $request->validated(). I understand that the new variable doesnt not being validated with the request but is there anyway to get the new form request after merged?

Before Merge: dd($request->all());

```
array:2 [▼
  "Name" => "Jack"
  "Age"  => "12" 
]
```

Merge new variable with $request

```
$request->merge(['Fruit' => 'apple']);
```

After merge: dd($request->all());

```
array:3 [▼
  "Name" => "Jack"
  "Age"  => "12" 
  "Fruit"  => "Apple" 
]
```

After merge: dd($request->validated());

```
array:3 [▼
  "Name" => "Jack"
  "Age"  => "12" 
]
```

Request Rules

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Name' => 'nullable',
            'Age' => 'nullable',
            'Fruit' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Please can you show how you're instantiating the FormRequest class and also where you're calling `merge()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `prepareForValidation`, like this in your Request class:

```php
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'Fruit' => 'Apple',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a request variable like this:

```
$request->request->add(['Fruit' => 'apple']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class RequestExample extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * @return Validator
     */
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $this->modifyRequestExampleRecords();
        return parent::getValidatorInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'Name'  => 'nullable',
            'Age'   => 'nullable',
            'Fruit' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function modifyRequestExampleRecords(): void
    {
        $this->request->add([
            "Fruit" => "apple"
        ]);
    }
}
```

Pass `RequestExample $request` as your method parameter. And then write `dd($request->validated());` or `dd($request->all());`. You will get the 3 properties as well. But please try to avoid `$request->all();`. Because, SQL injection can be occurred by using this. So better to use `$request->validated();` everywhere.